# Playback Video in iOS inside a custom view

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

I am trying to build a simple app that allows me to record a video and then watch it. I am using two views, `AVCamPreviewView` on the left side of the screen (which displays a live video stream from the iPhone's camera) and `AVPlayerLayerView` on the right side of the screen (which is supposed to display the video once I have recorded and saved it to the app's document folder).

While the first part (displaying the livestream) works like a charm (I used Apple's AVCam-tutorial for reference), the latter does not: I can start the playback of the video that I have recorded: The Audio starts playing, but I cannot see anything, and I have no clue why that is.

Here is my `AVPlayerLayerView`-class:

```
//
//  AVPlayerLayerView.swift
//  AVCamSwift
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AVPlayerLayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("AVPlayerLayerView -> init with frame")

        inits()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("AVPlayerLayerView -> init with coder")

        inits()
    }

    private func inits() {
        let rootLayer: CALayer = self.layer
        rootLayer.masksToBounds = true

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        rootLayer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    func setContentUrl(url: NSURL) {
        print("Setting up item: \(url)")
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
        player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(item)
    }

    func play() {
        if (player.currentItem != nil) {
            print("Starting playback!")
            player.play()
        }
    }

    func pause() {
        player.pause()
    }

    func rewind() {
        player.seekToTime(CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1))
    }

    func stop() {
        pause()
        rewind()
    }
}
```

The video-playback should start when the corresponding button is tapped, and here is the code that starts the playback:

```
@IBAction func playVideoTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let rfp = recordingFilePath {
        playbackView.setContentUrl(rfp)
        playbackView.play()
    }
}
```

**As mentioned before: Audio-Playback works, but I cannot see anything, thus I assume I have to reposition the AVPlayerLayer in my AVPlayerLayerView-Class or something like that. Any ideas?**

And here's a snippet of the layout, just in case it helps...
[image: Layout]

EDIT:

Thanks to Rajesh's response I am finally able to playback the video. However, the recorded video is not displayed inside the right, grey area of the screen, but instead inside a tiny square in the top-middle of the screen (see screenshot). Any ideas how to fix that? Also, aspect ratio is not the same as in the "recording view"...

[image: Wrong location of AVPlayerLayer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot setting bounds for the avplayer layer.

```
private func inits() {

        //let rootLayer: CALayer = self.layer
       // rootLayer.masksToBounds = true

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        avPlayerLayer.bounds = self.bounds
       // avPlayerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
        self.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, that answer helped a lot, however the behaviour is not as intended. Please see the edit of my question above. Do you have any idea how to get on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Awesome, found the solution. First of all, Rajesh's answer helped me a lot, that's why he's gonna get my checkmark, secondly, adding

```
avPlayerLayer.bounds = self.layer.bounds
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.layer.frame.width,     self.layer.frame.height)
```

to my play()-method did the trick. Setting up the bounds in the inits() method as shown by Rajesh leaves you with the problem, that the bounds are set before the view did appear, and thus values may be wrong. Setting the frame as suggested above helps to position the CAPlayerLayer correctly and also setup the aspect ratio as intended!